# How can I create the following table with the mentioned specifications?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, margins, itemize

I am having trouble creating a table on Overleaf which was already created in Word. The table has 10 rows, but knowing how to producte the first 2-3 rows will be sufficient to reproduce myslef the entire table. The 3 first rows of the table look as follows:

[image]

I am not an experienced user of Overleaf and, therefore, despite having tried for a while to reproduce the mentioned table, in the end, I didn't succeed. Then, I would be glad if you could indicate to me which steps and commands I should follow in order to reproduce this table in Overleaf. Alternatively, if you could provide me with the code corresponding to the first two rows of the table, it would be splendid.

What I would like to achieve and I failed to date is the following: to maintain the same (or similar) line spacing, put the items' part, conserve all the text alignment (cantered alignment for 1st and 3rd columns' cells and for the first cell of 2nd column, and justified alignment for the rest of 2nd column's cells), the fact that at the end of each line of text there is enough separation with the table vertical lines, and the fact that "Dedicaió (hores)" of the last column appears as in the table (in two different lines and with a bit of separation from the table horizontal lines).

I will appreciate all the help you could provide me.

Regards,

Ela

Comment: Please show the code you tried to create your self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As starting point. For more, you need to show us, what you try so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\setlist[itemize]{nosep, leftmargin=*}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c,m] X[l,m] Q[c, m]},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, c},
             stretch=-1,%<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                        % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
              measure = vbox,
              rowsep=5pt
             }
Setmana  & some text    &   {text\\ text}  \\
{text\\ date\\ -- \\
 text\\ date}   &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Text.
                \item   Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text
                \item   text
                    \end{itemize}   &   24  \\
{text\\ date\\ -- \\
 text\\ date}   &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Text.
                \item   Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text
                \item   text
                    \end{itemize}   &   40  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Zarko,
Thank you so much for your rapid response! I appreciate your time and the template provided, it has been of great help! With that I have been able to complete the entire table.
Best,
Ela

Comment: @Ela, you are welcome! Happy TeXing !